# Create a report of 10k rows from MongoDB - Python API

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, api, report

I would like to create an excel / google sheet using python that contains about 10-12k rows fetched from a mongo database.

The flow is tha the user requests this data from an admin panel, which calls an api to generate this report and emails it to the team.

The sheet will contain 25-30 columns and about 10-12k rows.

How can I do this effectively with Python 3+?

It would be expensive to call the api for each order so I figured I'll paginate the data, however what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Pagination does not apply to batch processes.

Comment: @D.SM ah :( that brings me back to square 1. Can you suggest a different approach? I am thinking of allocating a cloud function for this.

Comment: This is a site for answering specific questions. Your question is "how can I write a report" which is not answerable in SO format.